# HDinsight python packages for pyspark 3

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

I followed a tutorial provided by Microsoft to install python packages using the script actions feature on the azure portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-python-package-installation

This seems to only install the packages so that they are accessible through the pyspark kernel rather than both the pyspark and pyspark 3 kernel. I was wonder if anyone knows of a way to get it to be seen by the pyspark 3 kernel?

Answer (score 1):

fixed by change directory
was

```
/usr/bin/anaconda/bin/pip
```

to

```
/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from GLalor is great, but still didn't work for me using conda until I added -n py35 to my code:

```
/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/conda install -y -c conda-forge ggplot
```

Installed in the PySpark2 environment, whereas:

```
/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/conda install -y -c conda-forge ggplot -n py35
```

Did correctly install to be useable in a PySpark3 session. My novice guess is that conda recognizes 2 as the default environment, regardless of the filepath to install.